# Error:(7, 22) java: ')' expected when executing my code

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I receive the following error:

> Error:(7, 22) java: ')' expected when executing my code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        myName( mName:"Gowtham");
    }

    public static void myName(String mName) {
        System.out.println(mName);
    }
}
```

This is the code I wanted to execute but it tells it has errors, learning it through some online courses.

Comment: Java doesn't have named arguments. Either you're using a bad course, or it is for a different language than Java.

Answer (score 1):

The error is here

```
myName( mName:"Gowtham");
```

Just write it as following:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        myName("Gowtham");
    }

    public static void myName(String mName) {
        System.out.println(mName);
    }
}
```